# Header, navigation bar and left menu together - ionic

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile, ionic-framework

I am developing an application in which every page has header.
And on left corner of header, there should be left menu.
This app contains around 20-30 pages and moving it from jqm to ionic.

I got multiple example but having header and navigation bar at same position.
Please help me out on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please go through following link:  http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/header-navigation-bar-and-left-menu-together/18355

Answer (score 5):

You can have both the navigation bar and header bar in a same view. You can use `ion-nav-bar` directive (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavBar/) to have a fixed navigation bar on top and can use `ion-header-bar` with class `bar-subheader` to create a sub header. http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionHeaderBar/

Sample code showing both is below:

```
 <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon ion-navicon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button button-icon ion-search"></button>
    <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-email"></button>
    <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-person"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
     <h1 class="title"> Main Nav bar</h1>
  </ion-nav-bar>
 <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced bar-subheader">
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-chevron-left"></button>
   <h2 class="title">Sub Header</h2>
 </ion-header-bar>
<ion-content has-subheader="true">
  <h1> Sub header example</h1>
 </ion-content>
```

Working sample is available in this code pen link:
http://codepen.io/svswaminathan/pen/MYBrgM